# What is the difference between ' and " in C?

Tags: c, syntax, char, string-literals, comparison-operators

'q' will work fine to exit, but "q" does not.

What's the difference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){
  char c;
  while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 && c != "q");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'` is for characters, `"` is for strings. A string is basically an array of characters that ends with a NUL (`'\0'`).

Comment: @strupo: there is not data type `string` in  `c`. And `'` cannot take characters, but only one `char`.

Comment: @raiserle yes, you are correct, that is what I meant. Also, a `char *` or `char[]` is usually referred to as a string.

Comment: @strupo: Array of `char` is not a string ;). the `string` data type ist defined in `c++` not in pure `c`

Comment: Hmmm..... C book is needed not Q&A forum

Answer (score 2):

With ", you create a `char[]`, with ', you create a `char`acter. They're similar, but not quite the same: A character is just an ASCII value between 0 and 255 (like a `byte`), a `char[]` is a string of ASCII values with some kind of terminator to tell the code that that's the end of the string (a zero character in this case, \0).
You can only put a single character into '' because it's only 1 character, but as many as you want into "", unless of course you run out of RAM, because it's an array.

Also, since you want to compare it to a variable of the type char it can't be a string because that would mean comparing different types (and as far as I know, an array/string/`char[]`/whatever is pretty much a pointer, and comparing a memory address and a character variable is a bit weird in that moment), but you could use `myCharArray[0]`, because that way you get the first item of the array, and that's a `char`acter.

Comment: no `string` data type in  `c`

Comment: Or char[] or whatever. Let me change that.

Answer (score 2):

`'q'` is a character constant that represents a single character.

`"q"` is a character array (string literal) of the type `char[2]` that has characters `{ 'q', '\0' }`.

The comparison of a single character with a string literal like

```
c == "q"
```

or

```
c != "q"
```

does not make a sense and the compiler will issue an error message because in fact there is compared an integer (the character after the integer promotion) with a pointer (after the implicit conversion of the string literal to pointer to its first element)

Answer (score 0):

'c' is a character
"c" is a string containing the character c and '\0'

Comment: no `string` data type in `c`

Comment: yes, meant array of chars